# libc6 install-info error

Tags: 14.04

I was trying to update my ubuntu and it crashed on updating libc6.
So I tried to run this line by itself:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6
```

I get the following

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libc6 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 240 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/etc/environment: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I guess this means that some config file is formatting wrong but which one and how do I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Whats the output of `sed -n '2 p' /etc/environment`?

Comment: oh... it's my HTTP_PROXY line.... Parts of the password are symbols

Comment: How did you put it? Replace password with other texts..

Comment: I added in "" ie from `HTTP_PROXY = http://user:Password@192.168.1.1:8000` to `HTTP_PROXY = "http://user:Password@192.168.1.1:8000"` in my `/etc/environment` and everything works now. Thanks

Comment: Please add that as an answer and accept it so that future readers can take help from that..

Answer (score 0):

In my `/etc/environment` file I had proxy variables.

```
http_proxy=http://user:password@192.168.1.1:6000
https_proxy=https://user:password@192.168.1.1:6000
```

this was causing the `apt-get install` to fail
changing it to:

```
http_proxy="http://user:password@192.168.1.1:6000"
https_proxy="https://user:password@192.168.1.1:6000"
```

fixes that